# Tuples without field names

Tags: nim-lang

I noticed I can declare tuples in nimrod without giving names for each filed. For example:

```
type T1 = tuple[string, age: int]
type T2 = tuple[char, string, age: int]
```

But this doesn't apply for the last filed

```
type T3 = tuple[string, int] # compilation error
```

Why is that? Is this intended? Why should the last field always be named?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The compiler actually interprets `T1` as a tuple with fields named `string` and `age` both of type `int` and `T2` as a tuple with fields named `char`, `string`, and `age` of type `int`. In short, the standalone "types" in the comma-separated list are interpreted as field names.

This is likely a compiler bug (as you can't use the field names for constructors) in that it doesn't validate the field names. But it's not that you have to provide a type for the last element only: the type will apply to all the elements in the comma-separated list preceding the colon.